# Question about #define statement in Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm not experienced in C, so I'm not comfortable with this statement in this C / objective-C project.

```
#define CBLog(...) NSLog(@"%s [%ld]: %@", basename(__FILE__), __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
```

Questions:

1. the 3 dots (...) are used to indicate CBLog() is a method with parameters ? What do they mean ?
2. %ld stands for line format ? what's the d in %ld for ?
3. **FILE** , **LINE** and **VA_ARGS** are default replacement tokens for the C debugger ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `...` means the macro accepts any number of arguments.

`%ld` is a string formatter meaning 'long decimal', where decimal really means integer.

`__FILE__` expands to the current file name

`__LINE__` expands to the current line number

`__VA_ARGS__` expands to the arguments passed to the macro.

The debugger has nothing to do with it.  All of this is the preprocessor, except `%ld` which is string formatting.

Answer (score 2):

1. `...` means that any number of arguments can be given.
2. `%ld` means `signed long`, though it's a bit strange as I've never seen signed line numbers.
3. `__FILE__` is the current source file's filename. `__LINE__` is the current line number. `__VA_ARGS__` are the arguments given to the macro.